# Eclipse Juno - Hangs on Type Space loading

Tags: eclipse-juno

Don't know what happened, but it just hangs on "Type Space loading (4%)" and that's it. I tried to solve problem with -clean option and with deleting .history and eclipse resources folder under plugins. I also tried with new workspace and it's still the same.

Before that I installed JVET. Don't know if it's connected with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because of VJET, see https://www.ebayopensource.org/jira/browse/VJET-57

To me it happened on a fresh installation of Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers. 
Just leave it for about half an hour and it should finish successfully.

May i ask why did you install VJET? If as me to be able to debug node.js you might wanna try https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

Comment: I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot.